# Lua io.write() not working

Tags: lua, io

I am using a luvit Lua environment to run my lua code through my control panel. I am looking to write to a .txt file, but with the simple code that i am running, its not working.

The reason I wish to write to a .txt file is to log notices from my Discord Bot I am working on in the Discordia library.

I have a folder called MezzaBOT. In this file i have a write.lua file and also a log.txt file. I have this simple code in my write.lua file:

```
io.output('log.txt')
io.write('hello\n')
io.close()
```

I then run in my command promt with Luvit environment:

```
>luvit Desktop\mezzabot\write.lua
```

I don't get any errors but the log.txt file continues to stay empty. Am I missing a line in my code, or do i need to access log.txt differently?

edit: my new code is the following

```
file = io.open('log.txt')
file:write('hello', '\n')
file:close()
```

and it is not making a new line for each time with \n

edit B:

Ok, i found my problem, its creating a log.txt in my C:\Users\PC.
One other problem is when writing, its not making a new line with the \n. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Call `io.close()` when you're done with the file to flush the pending writes.

Comment: Or use `io.flush()` after series of `io.write()`

Comment: Use `io.write('hello\n')` to see it immediately in the log.

Comment: my new code now io.output('log.txt')
io.write('hello\n')
io.close() and it still wont work

Comment: Works for me ([“screenshot”](https://hastebin.com/sujutopolo.shell)).  I'm voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: Ok i found the problem, its making a new file called log in my Users\PC. the \n isnt creating a new line. Can anyone fix this?

Comment: `\n` always creates a new line.  It is absolutely impossible that it doesn't.  It's a control character.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: its not im not sure why, its only adding a space in my .txt file. Im getting hello hello hello hello hello

Comment: is it because im in append mode when i am opening the file? also the code is now file = io.open('log.txt') io.write('hello', '\n') io.close()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua, by default, opens files in *read* mode. You need to explicitly open a file in *write* mode if you want to write to it ([see manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.open))

```
file = io.open('log.txt', 'w')
file:write('hello', '\n')
file:close()
```

Should work :)